# Is there any linux command to update rxjs-compat version ^6.5.1 to ~6.3.3

Tags: angular

In my package.json file -

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.1",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
},
```

I've the above.How can I change "rxjs-compat" version to "~6.3.3"

Answer (score 0):

You should use npm to uninstall the related package first: `npm uninstall rxjs-compat` , then `npm install rxjs-compat@6.3.3`